# Card Height adjusting on Button Click React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to adjust this one whenever I click "Create Invoice" it will render a spinner with "Creating invoice". However the height of the card is also changing. I want it to be in fixed position

Please check GIF
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSlXh.jpg

````
const Loading = () => {
  return (
    <div className="loading" style={divStyle}>
      <h4>Creating Invoice
        <Spinner size="15px" color="#6491c6"/></h4>
    </div> 

  )}```
````

Comment: No one can help you with this if you don't share the code of className ```loading``` and ```divStyle```. Please update the question.

Answer (score 1):

could you share what are you putting in **loading** class and **divStyle** ?
I think you should add height of 40 and center it vertically if it's not centred on one of those classes:

```
display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 40px;
```

Comment: Already sorted,  I just enclosed it  with <></> in my card file and it works. Thank you though.